# How to set up rails git repos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, version-control

I want to git push to my rails app. I can't seem to find any information about it.

I want my rails app to be something like Heroku in a sense I could `git push` to it, though obviously building is a whole other matter.

How to be able to git push to rails app?

Comment: Can you brief it more?

Comment: You could use https://github.com/deis/deis . Or search for "paas" on github : https://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=paas&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories

Answer (score 0):

#### To Push into git you can follow those steps one after another

```
$ cd my_project
$ git init
$ git add *
$ git commit -m "My initial commit message"
$ git remote add origin git@example.com:my_project.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

#### To Push you rails app to heroku you have to follow the following steps

First install `gem heroku`

```
$ gem install heroku
```

then, Login to `heroku` with your credentials

```
$ heroku login
```

then, Add following `gem` to your `Gemfile`

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Make sure you add a specific `ruby` version in your `Gemfile`, ex: `ruby '2.1.2'`

run `$ bundle install`

Create `heroku app`

```
$ heroku create
```

Push to heroku

```
$ git push heroku master
```

Run `migrations`

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

that's it :) [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4) is a great documentation on `heroku` page, you can see for more details.

Comment: i want to have a rails app that I could git push to, not an env I can git push to that happens to be rails.

Comment: In other words, I'd like rails to receive, store, handle, manage pushes